# Create multiple modals by means of arrays

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am doing a project that contains many modals, but I realized that it has many lines of code, I would like to economize code, but I don't know how to handle it, I still don't understand matrices very well. Can anyone help me by giving me tips or suggestions? How should I reduce my lines of code? or how should I make the arrays?

This is my html code:

```js
const openEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-open]");
const closeEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-close]");
const isVisible = "is-visible";

for (const el of openEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const modalId = this.dataset.open;
    document.getElementById(modalId).classList.add(isVisible);
  });
}

for (const el of closeEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove(isVisible);
  });
}

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target == document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  // if we press the ESC
  if (e.key == "Escape" && document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});
```

```css
.open-modal {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
}

.modal.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: default;
}

.modal-dialog>* {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.modal-header {
  background: #efefef;
}

.modal-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.modal-header .close-modal {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.modal p+p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal1">MODAL 1 1</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal2">MODAL 2</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal3">MODAL 3</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal4">MODAL 4</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal5">MODAL 5</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal6">MODAL 6</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal7">MODAL 7</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal8">MODAL 8</button></div>

<div class="modal" id="modal1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <header class="modal-header">
      MODAL 1
      <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> ✕ </button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-content">
      <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="modal2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <header class="modal-header">
      MODAL 2
      <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> ✕ </button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-content">
      <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="modal3">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <header class="modal-header">
      MODAL 3
      <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> ✕ </button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-content">
      <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="modal4">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <header class="modal-header">
      MODAL 4
      <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> ✕ </button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-content">
      <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
      <p>Nullam vitae enim vel diam elementum tincidunt a eget metus. Curabitur finibus vestibulum rutrum. Vestibulum semper tellus vitae tortor condimentum porta. Sed id ex arcu. Vestibulum eleifend tortor non purus porta dapibus</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="modal" id="modal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <header class="modal-header">
        MODAL 5
        <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> ✕ </button>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-content">
        <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal" id="modal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <header class="modal-header">
        MODAL 6
        <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> ✕ </button>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-content">
        <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal" id="modal3">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <header class="modal-header">
        MODAL 7
        <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> ✕ </button>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-content">
        <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal" id="modal4">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <header class="modal-header">
        MODAL 8
        <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> ✕ </button>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-content">
        <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
        <p>Nullam vitae enim vel diam elementum tincidunt a eget metus. Curabitur finibus vestibulum rutrum. Vestibulum semper tellus vitae tortor condimentum porta. Sed id ex arcu. Vestibulum eleifend tortor non purus porta dapibus</p>
      </section>
    </div>
```

I appreciate any help, I am new to development!

Comment: Is your modal content coming from any data store? Or are they all static? 
You could have 1 modal in your HTML, and then on the open modal action, update the html content in JS to be the selected content..

Comment: Why are there `</div>` after every `</button>` at the beginning? I don't see anything wrong with this code per se. Yes, you could templatize it to replace, say, the title and body, but that just adds a different set of limits (what attributes can contain). Unless your modals are truly cookie-cutter (which would be unusual), it's usually best to opt for composability over rigid definition, IMHO.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The problem is that these modals go inside a carousel and the carousel goes inside an accordion, so leaving the modals like that, the code is quite extensive! and the <div> is because in addition to the button there is an image, but I had not added it. Thank you for the recommendations

Answer (score 0):

Its bit unclear what is goal here in production as we dont know what content should be inside.

But as suggested:

you can use one modal template and on click of button use that one only to show different content inside:

```
for (const el of openEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    document.getElementById("modal1").querySelector(".modal-content").innerHTML = "this is " + event.target.dataset.open
    document.getElementById("modal1").classList.add(isVisible);
  });
}
```

here I used event to get clicked button:

```
el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
```

and then update content based on that button:

```
document.getElementById("modal1").querySelector(".modal-content").innerHTML = "this is " + event.target.dataset.open
```

As far as the content goes you could create an object in JS with keys and content  as values where key would be reference to `event.target.dataset.open`.

and update `innerHTML` accordingly using that objects values.

```js
const openEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-open]");
const closeEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-close]");
const isVisible = "is-visible";

for (const el of openEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    document.getElementById("modal1").querySelector(".modal-content").innerHTML = "this is " + event.target.dataset.open
    document.getElementById("modal1").classList.add(isVisible);
  });
}

for (const el of closeEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove(isVisible);
  });
}

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target == document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  // if we press the ESC
  if (e.key == "Escape" && document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});
```

```css
.open-modal {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
}

.modal.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: default;
}

.modal-dialog>* {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.modal-header {
  background: #efefef;
}

.modal-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.modal-header .close-modal {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.modal p+p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal1">MODAL 1 1</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal2">MODAL 2</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal3">MODAL 3</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal4">MODAL 4</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal5">MODAL 5</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal6">MODAL 6</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal7">MODAL 7</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal8">MODAL 8</button></div>

<div class="modal" id="modal1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <header class="modal-header">
      MODAL 1
      <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> ✕ </button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-content">
      <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

And example with object data:

```js
const openEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-open]");
const closeEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-close]");
const isVisible = "is-visible";


const obj = [{
  key: "modal1",
  content: "modal1 content"
}, {
  key: "modal2",
  content: "modal2 content"
}, {
  key: "modal3",
  content: "modal3 content"
}, {
  key: "modal4",
  content: "modal4 content"
}, {
  key: "modal5",
  content: "modal5 content"
}, {
  key: "modal6",
  content: "modal6 content"
}, {
  key: "modal7",
  content: "modal7 content"
}, {
  key: "modal8",
  content: "modal8 content"
}]



for (const el of openEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

    const res = obj.filter(e => e.key === event.target.dataset.open)[0].content

    document.getElementById("modal1").querySelector(".modal-content").innerHTML = "this is " + res
    document.getElementById("modal1").classList.add(isVisible);

  });
}

for (const el of closeEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove(isVisible);
  });
}

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target == document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  // if we press the ESC
  if (e.key == "Escape" && document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});
```

```css
.open-modal {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
}

.modal.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: default;
}

.modal-dialog>* {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.modal-header {
  background: #efefef;
}

.modal-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.modal-header .close-modal {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.modal p+p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal1">MODAL 1 1</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal2">MODAL 2</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal3">MODAL 3</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal4">MODAL 4</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal5">MODAL 5</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal6">MODAL 6</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal7">MODAL 7</button></div>
<button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal8">MODAL 8</button></div>

<div class="modal" id="modal1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <header class="modal-header">
      MODAL 1
      <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> ✕ </button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-content">
      <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excuse me I was not clear when I asked my question, you are right, but what I want to do is that within each modal there is a carousel, so I want to shorten the code, but thank you very much! your code has helped me a lot! I have a question, if I want to make a list of modals for each option of an accordion, in each option of the accordion I make a template of the modal, yes?

Comment: @CamilaAndreaCárdenas Im sorry im having a bit of trouble to understand what is going on in: `The problem is that these modals go inside a carousel and the carousel goes inside an accordion`, and then `if I want to make a list of modals for each option of an accordion, in each option of the accordion` I got lost a bit here :) Maybe you could add another question with [mre] of this.

Comment: @CamilaAndreaCárdenas But in general you could  condition the click on modal to look for witch accordion and then witch carousel is shown or click and then fulfill the content based on objects data.  But is really hard for me to say this without seeing example.

Comment: Ok I have an accordion and when I click any option of this accordion it shows a slider with different buttons, when I click any button it opens the modals you helped me do. The question is that if for each accordion option should I make the modal template. Something like that:

1) First choice of the accordion
     2) Slider
       3) Modal template
1) Second choice of accordion
       2) Slider
          3) Modal template

do you understand me?

Comment: @CamilaAndreaCárdenas I believe you don't have to no, as you could somehow see witch accordion is active, you could add data in object to include also accordion's. And then filter the active one based on that additionally. Click of button would have to look witch accordion si active first, then look inside for witch button represents witch data from object for that specific accordion and Slider.